# Trying to require parts of jquery with webpack

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack

I am [using this article](http://alexomara.com/blog/webpack-and-jquery-include-only-the-parts-you-need/) to import only the parts of jquery that I would need.

However, I am running into an issue when doing using this code:

```
let $ = require('jquery/src/core');
require('jquery/src/core/init');
require('jquery/src/css');
console.log($);
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR in ./~/jquery/src/selector-sizzle.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ../external/sizzle/dist/sizzle in /home/vamsi/Do/highland-fun/bacon-form/node_modules/jquery/src
 @ ./~/jquery/src/selector-sizzle.js 1:0-14:3
```

This is my `webpack.config.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
    entry:'./app',
    output:{
      filename:'./bundle'
    },
    modules:{
      loaders:[
        {
           test:/jquery[\\\/]src[\\\/]selector\.js$/,
           loaders:['amd-define-factory-patcher-loader']
        }
      ]
    }
}
```

I have tried to use a `resolve.alias` to fix this:

```
resolve:{                                                                
  alias:{                                                                
   '../external/sizzle/dist/sizzle':'./node_modules/sizzle/dist/sizzle.js'
  }                                                                      
}
```

But it still throws the same error as before.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## The Problem

> I am [using this article](http://alexomara.com/blog/webpack-and-jquery-include-only-the-parts-you-need/) to import only the parts of jquery that I would need.

This article was written before jquery 2.2.0 was released.

In **jquery 2.1.x**:

```js
// jquery/src/selector-sizzle.js

define([
    "./core",
    "sizzle"
], function( jQuery, Sizzle ) {
  //...
})
```

So `sizzle` is resolved as `<base-dir>/node_modules/sizzle`

However in **jquery 2.2.x**:

```js
// jquery/src/selector-sizzle.js

define([
    "./core",
    "../external/sizzle/dist/sizzle" // <- missing
], function( jQuery, Sizzle ) {
  //...
})
```

If you look in `<base-dir>/node_modules/jquery` you'll see that `<base-dir>/node_modules/jquery/external` is missing. This directory exists in the jquery repo, but ignored within the jquery npm package.

## Solutions

Unfortunately, I didn't manage to solve this with webpack's `resolve.alias` in any way. 
Alternatively,  **one of these solutions** will work for you:

- Use jquery 2.1.4 -> `"jquery": "~2.1.4"`
- Stay with jquery 2.2.x and use [string-replace-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/string-replace-loader) as a pre-loader to replace `"../external/sizzle/dist/sizzle"` with `"sizzle"`:

`npm i string-replace-loader --save-dev`

```js
// webpack.config.js

module.exports = {
    //...
    module: {
        preLoaders: [{
            test: /jquery[\\\/]src[\\\/]selector-sizzle\.js$/,
            loader: 'string-replace',
            query: {
                search: '../external/sizzle/dist/sizzle',
                replace: 'sizzle'
            }
        }]
    }
    //...
};
```

**Note**: In both solutions you will have to `npm i sizzle --save`